# How to hide list of users from a user on ubuntu server 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, user-management

I would like to hide the list of users of my Ubuntu 16.04 server from a user logged in via ssh. I can remove the read permission on /home/ directory, but the logged in user can still read /etc/passwd file.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Look for [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot)

Comment: Use LXC, more modern then chroot. They then ssh into the LXC guest rather then the host.